# Using one table to store different data types/attributes in cakephp 3.x

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm developing an Escort site where a Escort has a a big number of attributes, I want to use one table for all, I'm not able to save these relationship.

Attributes table looks like it:

```sql
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| value    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The values on this table are like it:

```sql
+----+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | value               | category       | created             | modified            |
+----+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | White               | Ethnicities    | 2019-09-19 00:00:00 | 2019-09-19 00:00:00 |
|  2 | Blond               | hairColors     | 2019-09-20 00:00:00 | 2019-09-20 00:00:00 |
|  3 | p                   | Manequins      | 2019-09-20 00:00:00 | 2019-09-20 00:00:00 |
|  4 | Short               | hairHeights    | 2019-09-20 00:00:00 | 2019-09-20 00:00:00 |
|  5 | Brunette            | Ethnicities    | 2019-09-23 00:00:00 | 2019-09-23 00:00:00 |
|  6 | Hotel               | Places         | 2019-09-23 00:00:00 | 2019-09-23 00:00:00 |
|  7 | Own Place           | Places         | 2019-09-23 00:00:00 | 2019-09-23 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

attributes_escorts Table looks like it:

```sql
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| escort_id    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| attribute_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm looking for a way to link tables in this way on EscortsTable.php:

```php
$this->hasOne('Ethnicities', [
            'className' => 'attributes',
            'foreignKey' => 'escort_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'attribute_id',
            'conditions' => [
            'category' => 'Ethnicities'
        ]]);

$this->belogsToMany('Places', [
            'className' => 'attributes',
            'foreignKey' => 'escort_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'attribute_id',
            'conditions' => [
            'category' => 'Places'
        ]]);
```

In this way, i'm able to get some data on Escorts Controller:

```php
$ethnicities = $this->Escorts->Ethnicities->find('list');
```

But not able to save when add a new escort.. nothing is populated on attributes_escorts.

Theres a way to do it? Or I'll need to create a table for each attributte?

Thanks!

Comment: If you posted some code related to saving it might help in debugging. Checkout https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations you are using an intermediary table (attributes_escorts) for relationships but didn't list it in your relationships (using the 'through' option), could be the main problem, depending on how you're adding new attributes

Comment: I'll look for 'through' option. Thanks